# SeekBarProperties not working

Tags: android, android-preferences

I've put a SeekBarPreference in my PreferenceScreen (xml), but the value isn't saved and also the default value isn't taken in account.
The bar is always at zero.

Here the piece of code:

```
<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="mySettings">
    <SeekBarPreference
            android:key="m_set"
            android:defaultValue="210"
            android:title="Transparency"
            android:max="255"
            android:summary="Adjust..." />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Any idea?
Other stuff like CheckBoxPreference works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no SeekBarPreference, you must create own class, check:
[this tutorial](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/for-almost-any-application-we-need-to.html)